# EF 6.0.0 - Not creating Database from scratch

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I am using a .NET 4.0 project. I installed the EF -version 6.0.0 nuget package.

I've added a class library, installed EF, then enabled migrations, added my DB Context class, and inside my App.config, I added this config section:

```
<contexts>
  <context
    type="DataLayer.MiddlewareDbContext, DataLayer">
    <databaseInitializer
      type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[
        DataLayer.MiddlewareDbContext, DataLayer], 
        [DataLayer.Migrations.Configuration, DataLayer]], EntityFramework" />
  </context>
</contexts>
```

When I run the application, I get the following exceptions when I try to access the DB Context:

```
Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.ColumnModel System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Builders.ColumnBuilder.String(System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations.AnnotationValues>)'.
```

Also note that the Database is not being created!

The Migrations folder already contains a single migration file containing all models I have + Configuration class.

Appreciate checking this out.

Regards

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having this exact error while migrating my database.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior can happen when multiple versions of EntityFramework have been installed through Nuget on different projects in the same solution.

This can be fixed by opening the Package Manager for the Solution, selecting the latest version of EntityFramework, clicking Manage, and selecting all projects. This will then update all older versions to the same version.

Comment: Nailed it! V6.1.1 in the EF project and V6.0.0 in the Web project in the same solution.
By the way: in VS2013 the project worked. When I opened it in VS2015 the problem started.